# Создание таблиц в SQLite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Пытаюсь сделать блог на Django. Для этого использую SQLite. У меня получается связь один ко многим - статьи к комментариям:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "article"

    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article_text = models.TextField()
    article_date = models.DateTimeField()
    article_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Comments(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'comments'

    comments_text = models.TextField()
    comments_article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

Возникает вот такая ошибка:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'comments_article' to comments without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

Где мне надо задать значение по умолчанию ? Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это происходит из-за того, что в базе уже хранятся ранее добавленные комментарии и после миграции они не будут привязаны ни к какой статье, что не соответствует модели. Нужно удалить все комментарии из БД, например, с помощью административной панели Django.

Comment: А можно примерно того как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Если администаторская панель включена в настройках и создан суперопользователь для проекта, нужно зарегистрировать модель комментариев, добавив в файл `admin.py` (который находится в папке приложения) 2 строчки: `from myproject.myapp.models import Comments` и `admin.site.register(Comments)`, а затем можно будет зайти в админ. панель по стандартной ссылке `/admin/` и там уже можно удалять/добавлять/редактировать записи.
Подробнее:
http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/contrib/admin/index.html
и тут: http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/django-admin.html?highlight=createsuperuser#django-admin-createsuperuser

Comment: А вообще, это правильно так делать с комментариями ? Может лучше было бы создать новый application ?

Comment: Это влияет только на наглядность. Разделить в любой момент можно, например, когда этот application станет слишном большой. По поводу блога советую первые 2 плейлиста отсюда: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/projects/
Там как раз про строительство блога с комментариями, плюс исходники есть. Но надо понимать английский.

Comment: но сайт-то платный

Comment: Первая часть бесплатная, вторая есть на ютубе https://www.youtube.com/user/CodingEntrepreneurs/playlists
А исходники на гитхабе всегда бесплатные были.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41092/discussion-between-faoxis-and-user5720164).